# What can I use to keep a smartphone cool while recording 4k video?

Tags: technology, temperature

My smartphone (Sony Xperia Z5)  gets very hot while recording 4k video (around the CPU area). Is there anything I can use to keep it cool?

I don't want to put anything on directly on the phone, but I'm hoping to incorporate something into the case.

Comment: Could down voters leave some comments at least

Comment: ^--Your question is off-topic

Comment: if that is the case, why has it not been closed yet ...

Comment: It's been voted to close, you just can't see it. If it remains open, good for you. If it gets closed good for me. Time and one more user will decide. In case it does get closed you can edit it to improve it and it will be in review to see if it can be reopened just the way the system works.

Comment: Why exactly is it off topic?  There are a tens of other questions similar to this. I don't t mm see this as any different

Comment: How hot is very hot? Phones can handle more heat than one might think, i've had it at 85 degrees celcius once. I don't really see the problem with a phone that's a bit hot.

Comment: So hot that the phone turns off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this. Usually before I use it over my eyes. I refrigerate it for some time. After the gel is cool enough, you could stick it on the back of the phone. This will cool the phone down.

[image: relaxing gel eye pad]
[Amazon link of relaxing gel eye pads](http://www.amazon.in/Relaxing-Strap-Velcro-Cooling-Relaxation/dp/B00JFOLHEK)

Comment: How long does the gel stay cool?  Does it have heat dissipating properties?

Comment: I have used on my eyes for 15-20 mins, it stayed efficient, though eventually gel dries out if continuously exposed to heat. So usually we store it in the refrigerator, to make it last longer. Hope that helps

Comment: this seems to be the best thing to do. I wonder if there is such a gel that permanently stays cool, without having to put it into the fridge.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a fan to blow air over it while you are recording. This will help to alleviate some of the heat issues.

If you have a case on the phone, remove it to assist with the heat exchange from the air.  Cases tend to act like insulation when it comes to heat.

Comment: That would cause problems with the audio. I would then need to use a microphone which would be useless. I try to record my 2 month old daughter for her grand parents, but the microphone would be distracting.

Comment: You could cover the internal microphone with "fuzz" (I don't know the technical term) to limit the noise from the air flow. This material is useful because it allows sound through without the annoying white noise of air flow.